# How to open Modal on submit button based on form options chosen and finish submit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First of all I know very little about ruby or ruby on rails. I have only been coding a few years, my language of choice was python. I have built a few apps and my dev team decided I should start helping with our rails stack, so I winging it. Please excuse my ignorance in advance.

So I have a form on our forums which shows each group a user is in and a dropdown box for the email settings for each group. The user selects which options they want hit submits and then I have a function in my permissions controller that updates the db with the selections and redirects back to the home page.

I would like to add a modal so if the user selects opt-out as any selection I can open the modal and display a message. If you user selects ok I would like the modal to close and the submit to happen as it does. If the user hits cancel I would like the modal to close with no submit so the user can change the options they would like and submit again.

So far I have added the modal to html using the bootstrap guide and on the submit button. Now the modal opens on any choice for a second or two and the the submit redirects the page. I'm assuming I need some js to make this happen like I want. Also we are using haml.

```
.row
  .col-md-9
    %h4 My Groups
  .col-md-3
    %h4 Email Preferences
    %p Fake text for email pref explanations

.space
.row
  = form_with(url: update_collection_permissions_path, method: :put, local: true, html: {id: :email }) do |f|

    = will_paginate @discussion_groups, class: "digg_pagination"
    -if @discussion_groups.any?
      -@discussion_groups.each do |discussion_group|
        .col-md-9
          .panel.panel-default
            .panel-body
              .row
                .col-md-9
                  .row
                    -if current_user.admin?
                      %span.blue-text #{view_discussion_group(discussion_group)} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                      {destroy_discussion_group_link_for(discussion_group)}

                    -elsif discussion_group.admin_role.users.include?(current_user)
                      %span.blue-text #{view_discussion_group(discussion_group)} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    -else
                      %span.blue-text #{view_discussion_group(discussion_group)} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                      -#{contributor_link_for(discussion_group)} &nbsp;
              .row
                .body-text
                  =discussion_group.description

        .col-md-3
          =discussion_group.name
          -selected = discussion_group.permission_for_user(current_user)
          =f.select("permissions[#{selected.id}]", options_for_select([['Daily digest', 'daily_digest'], ['Opt-out', 'opt-out'], ['Individual', 'individual']], selected.email_preference), {}, class: 'form-control')
    -else
      .row
        You are not subscribed to any discussion groups.

    .col-md-9

    .col-md-3
      .buttonrow
        =link_to('Cancel', root_path, class: 'btn btn-default btn-lg',:rel=>"tooltip",:title=>"Return to previous page")
        =f.submit('Update', class: 'btn btn-default btn-lg','data-toggle'=>"modal", 'data-target'=>"#myModal" )

#myModal.modal.fade{:role => "dialog", :tabindex => "-1"}
  .modal-dialog{:role => "document"}
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        %button.close{"aria-label" => "Close", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"}
          %span{"aria-hidden" => "true"}
        %h4.modal-title Modal title
      .modal-body
        %p One fine body
      .modal-footer
        %button.btn.btn-default{"data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} Close
        %button.btn.btn-primary{:type => "button"} OK
```

So I only want the modal to open when opt-out is any selection and to close and submit if a user selects ok. If the user hasn't selected to opt-out I want the form just to submit. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need some js to make this happen. The code below will use jQuery library(as its used by bootstrap as a dependency)

Form has an id `email`, I would suggest you use a better name for id, like `form-purpose-of-the-form`
For simplicity, I'm gonna rename the form id to `form-email`

```
= form_with(url: update_collection_permissions_path, method: :put, local: true, html: {id: 'form-email' }) do |f|
```

Step 1. Remove the code to trigger bootstrap modal from the button

```
=f.submit('Update', class: 'btn btn-default btn-lg')
```

Step 2. Write some javascript to prevent form submission & open the modal instead, when our condition passes, else let it submit

```
$("#form-email").on('submit', function(event){
  // Considering your select box has an id called `x` you can first
  // check its value and then decide to open the modal
  var selected_value = $("#x").val()

  if(selected_value === 'opt-out'){
    event.preventDefault();  //Prevents form submission or the default event's action
    $("#myModal").modal('open'); // Open the modal though javascript
  }
})
```

Step 3. Add code, so that your modal button submits the form

```
.modal-footer
    %button.btn.btn-default{"data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} Close
    %button.btn.btn-primary{:type => "button", :form => "form-email"} OK
```

Let me know if it worked for you, or you're facing some issues.

Comment: This works so thanks Kumar, but how can I trigger the modal based off the user selection. I only want it to show if opt-out is selected so I can then show our opt-out warning. Otherwise I just want it to submit.

Comment: @YungFlizzy Added update, let me know if that works.

Comment: should I wrap this in a loop since it will return a value for each group the user is in?

Comment: Didn't see the loop there. Then you can give a class to the select box and try picking up the value from the class.

Comment: You will have to loop through all the values and anytime the value is true, you can break the loop and prevent form submission. Else it will return from the function and submit the form

Comment: Going to try that and report back. Also forgot to mention I had to use $("#myModal").modal('show'); instead of open

Comment: Ok so I have the js working. When opt-out is selected the modal launches. But the  OK button is not submitting the form to the controller, does nothing when clicked. The close button works, but the submit button on the non modal form is grayed out after so I added an onClick to refresh the page and that works.

Comment: For the ok button, set the type from :button to :submit, that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I finally figured this out for anyone else having this issue. What I wanted was a modal to pop up if a user tried to opt-out of the email settings when submitting the form. If they still wish to opt-out pressing the button in the modal should submit the changes to the rails controller.

1. I changed the form id as suggested

   ```
   form_with(url: update_collection_permissions_path, method: :put, local: true, html: 
   {id: :'form-email-pref' }) do |f|
   ```
2. I added some js to the form to get each of the selected values in an array. I then loop through each of the values and if one matches opt-out I prevent the default submit and show the model. Otherwise it should submit as normal.

   ```
   $("#form-email-pref").on('submit', function (event) {
   var selected = $('select :selected');
   $.each(selected, function(index, x) {
       if (x.value == 'opt-out') {
           event.preventDefault();
           $("#myModal").modal('show');
              }

           });

      });
   ```
3. To get the modal button to submit the external form I added some js to it. I used .off() to turn off the submit from step two. Otherwise it creates as loop because the selected option is still opt-out, but we are sure the user now wants to opt-out. Also we want to remove the modal at this point.

   ```
   $('#okButton').on('click', function (e) {
       $("#form-email-pref").off('submit')
       $("#form-email-pref").submit();
       $('#myModal').modal('hide');
   });
   ```
4. Lastly for the buttons in the modal. The cancel button will dismiss and refresh the page so the user can change options. The OK buttom will submit the form to the correct controller which handle the rest.

   ```
   %button.btn.btn-default{"data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => 
   "button",:onClick=>"window.location.reload()"} Close
   #okButton.button.btn.btn-primary{:type => "submit"}OK
   ```

Sure there is a better way to do it but considering I don't know rails. This is good enough for me as it serves the purpose. Thanks everyone for the help.